# Map an image file to a UV dome post-version 2.8

Tags: modeling, uv-image-editor

Version 2.92.

Created a UV sphere and lopped off half, so a hemisphere remains.

At present there are by default two panes in the UV Editing tab screen--*UV Editor* and *3D Viewport*, side by side.

After Edit Mode!UV!Unwrap in the right pane (in the 3D Viewport), the UV Editor (left pane) changes from a square grid and a cursor in the lower left, into a round grid that can accept a round map--where I've thus done so:

[image]

Meanwhile the 3D Viewport (right pane) contains the dome perspective, but it's still gray.

I want to map the .png in the left pane onto this dome in the right pane.  But how?

UPDATE:
Here is something in the "Base Color" field for *Material Properties*:
[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Hello :). @Aster17 is right, you need to assign the image texture to the object. It's only displayed in the UV editor, not chosen as a color :).

Comment: Where in the UV Editor do I perform this action?  I've looked high and low and see nothing about setting a material to image texture anywhere.

Comment: You need to do it in the Shader editor (or the Material panel you already have opened). UV editor is only for editing UV maps :)

Comment: Hey :). Just follow the link, it's all explained there with images.

Comment: I'm trying to translate the link app version into present day version.  I've just posted an update above where Material Properties!"Base Color" has an Image Texture option. It appears to have yielded something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen the pic you have provided and it is pretty clear that you haven't set the material to Image texture. Please change it to image texture and then try UV mapping it, then it should work.